# Impossibilidade de procurar varias string em um arquivo .txt

Tags: c++

Tive tentando fazer um programa ao qual pesquisa varias string em um .txt na linguagem de c++ porem só consigo pesquisar uma string

Meu código:

```
       #include <iostream>
       #include <string>
       #include <fstream>
       using namespace std;

int main()
{

         ifstream input;
    size_t pos;
          string line;

    input.open("t.txt");
    if(input.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(input,line))
        {
         pos = line.find("hey");
          if(pos!=string::npos) // string::npos is returned if string is not found
    {
        cout <<"Found!";
        break;
    }
        }
    }
```

Comment: obrigado,me ajudou muito,estou aprendo cada vez mais sobre progamação neste forum maravilhoso – Noob Zando

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução prática passa por guardar as palavras do arquivo num [`map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) ou num [`set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) e depois verificar forma direta, sem ter que navegar em cada linha do arquivo para cada verificação.

Um `map` ou um `set` também lhe garante uma procura bem eficiente das palavras, se a chave for a palavra em si.

Implementação com `set`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream input;
    set<string> words; //set para guardar todas as palavras do arquivo, sem repetições

    input.open("t.txt");
    if(input.is_open()) {
        string word;
        while(input >> word) { //percorrer palavra a palavra
            words.insert(word); //inserir a palavra
        }
    }

    vector<string> verifyWords = {"hey", "there", "people"}; //palavras a verificar
    for (auto word : verifyWords){ //para cada palavra
        if (words.find(word) != words.end()){ //se existe
            cout << word << " existe" << endl; //faz algo com ela
        }
    }
}
```

Optei por manter os nomes das variáveis em inglês para ter coerência com os que já tinha. Repare também que agora faço leitura no arquivo palavra a palavra ao invés de linha a linha.